# How to replace instance of string in SQL Server when followed by another pattern?

Tags: sql, sql-server, regex, sql-server-2005, replace

I have a [message] column which can contain hostname information - which I need to replace and remove parts of.

The statement I wrote to do this was:

```
update  table1
set     message = replace(replace(message ,'RL','NN'),'.COMPANY.COM','')
where   message is not NULL
```

So a hostname that appears as RL12345.COMPANY.COM will return as NN12345.

The issue is that if 'RL' appears anywhere else in the message column, it will be erroneously replaced. Is there a way to conditionally replace using a regex? 
I could verify that the number of numerical characters between RL and .COMPANY.COM was always between 7-9 for example.

To clarify, although RL will always be the beginning of the hostname string, it may not (and probably will not) be the beginning of the entire string in the message column.

e.g.:

"Tried to access RL12345.COMPANY.COM with no success"

There may also be multiple hostname instances in the one cell, all instances must be tansformed.

Comment: should RL always occur before the first `.` character?

Comment: Yes, RL will always be the first two letters of the hostname, and therefore will always precede the first . character

Comment: Sorry, to clarify - it will precede the first . character in the hostname, but not necessarily in the entire string.

Comment: how would you identify where the hostname starts in the message column then?

Comment: I guess that's part of the question, depending on the approach. At the moment I'm only replacing, but the hostname will always follow the pattern  RL[0-9]%.COMPANY.COM

Answer (score 0):

Looking for the string `'- RL'` may be sufficient:

```
update  table1
  set message = replace(replace(message, '- RL', '- NN'), '.COMPANY.COM',  '')
  where message like '%- RL[0-9]%.COMPANY.COM%';
```

A second approach is to simply look for the first occurrence and replace that.  Unfortunately, there is no option for `replace()` to only replace the first one, but you can hack it with other functions.  Something like this:

```
update  table1
  set message = left(message, charindex('- RL', message)) + '- NN') +  
                substring(message, charindex('- RL', message) + 4,
                          charindex('.COMPANY.COM', message) - charindex('- RL', message) - 4
                         ) +
                right(message, len(message) - charindex('.COMPANY.COM') - 12)
  where message like '%- RL[0-9]%.COMPANY.COM%';
```

Comment: The hostname is not normally preceded with "- ", unless I have misunderstood your syntax? 
There may also be multiple instances of a hostname within one cell.

Comment: @alexmc . . . The original version of the question appeared to have a hyphen before the `'RL'`.

Answer (score 0):

this seems to work, but you will have to run the update multiple time as it updates only 'RL' at a time

```
 update  table1
 set message  = case when isnumeric( substring(message ,charindex('RL',message )+2,7)) = 1 then   left(message ,charindex('RL',message )-1) + 'MN' + substring(id,charindex('RL',message )+2,1000 ) else message  end
```